# How to check the grid span of a CollectionView?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Here is my .xaml and .xaml.cs code.

```xml
...
<Button Text="1×1" x:Name="ChangeGridButton" Clicked="ChangeGridButtonClicked"/>
...
<CollectionView x:Name="NotesView" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="20" Spacing="2">
                <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="5">
                    ...
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
...
```

```cs
...
private async void ChangeGridButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NotesView.ItemsLayout == "VerticalGrid, 2") 
    {

    }
}
...
```

I want to check the grid span of the CollectionView but I get the following error message:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ItemsLayout' and 'String'

How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: according to the docs, `public Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IItemsLayout ItemsLayout { get; set; }`.  XAML typically uses helpers to convert strings to the correct property types

Comment: Comparing objects is very interesting subject. Because I use Java often, I am very careful when doing "==", even in other languages like C#

Comment: The `ItemsLayout` is not type of string, you can try to get the value of NotesView.ItemsLayout and then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Its not straightforward, because `ItemsLayout` gets set to different classes, for different layouts.

I think "VerticalGrid" becomes [GridItemsLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.griditemslayout).

The test might be:

```cs
if (ItemsLayout is GridItemsLayout gridLayout && gridLayout.Span == 2)
    ...
```

I haven't verified that code.

---

NOTE: I probably would not test that directly. Instead, I would have a member variable that I use to keep track of which layout I have set.

You likely only use two or three different layouts, right? Use a bool, int, or enum to keep track of which you set it to.